Arguments in favor of the statement "Everything that has an end must also have a beginning"
What logical arguments exist in favor of the statement "Everything that has an end must also have a beginning"?
So far I have either not found any, or they have been presented in a very brief form.

Usually this must be proven logically, because it is impossible to test all objects for the presence of a beginning and an end of their existence.

Obligatory Buddha quote: "Everything that has a beginning has an ending. Make your peace with that and all will be well." (the 'peace' part is what is important here)

Such generalisations are inductive reasoning:

A has an end and also a beginning.
B has an end and also a beginning.
C has an end and also a beginning.
...
D has an end, therefore it likely also has a beginning.

* In deductive reasoning, this would be a faulty generalisation fallacy.
It seems far worse-supported than just making a generalisation that "everything (that exists or has existed) has a beginning" from the fact that many things have beginnings.
That way, you can include everything that existed in the past, but also everything that still exist, which we've seen the beginning of, but not the end of.
... but that's still a generalisation many people reject (depending on how people try to use such an inference and what they're trying to infer has a beginning, of course). Also, all "beginnings" we see are actually just transformations of existing matter and energy, so that adds a significant asterisk here (although I've heard there are also quantum particles spontaneously popping into existence).

Pulling together several comments ([1]; [2]; [3]):

It is not logic, it is induction on experience. Our understanding of the world is not purely based on logic, as you seem to think. Very much is extrapolation based on experience and intuition, such as this claim.
[This claim is] a metaphysical claim based on empirical observations from the everyday dependent arising causal net, or you can abduct from the Latin term causa sui which apparently doesn't apply to anything that has an end.
Concrete things we encounter have both beginning and end, abstractions have neither. It is hard to come up with anything familiar at all that has one and not the other, and suggested examples are highly controversial metaphysical oddities.

